# awk system not setting variables properly

Tags: awk, system

I am having a issue in having the output of the grep (used in system() in nawk ) assigned to a variable .

```
nawk '{
CITIZEN_COUNTRY_NAME = "INDIA"
CITIZENSHIP_CODE=system("grep "CITIZEN_COUNTRY_NAME " /tmp/OFAC/country_codes.config   | cut -d @ -f1")
 }'/tmp/*****
```

The value IND is displayed in the console but when i give a printf the value of citizenshipcode is 0 - Can you pls help me here

printf("Country Tags|%s|%s\n", CITIZEN_COUNTRY_NAME ,CITIZENSHIP_CODE)

Contents of country_codes.config file

```
IND@INDIA
IND@INDIB
CAN@CANADA
```

Comment: Calling system from awk is a performance killer as it will be invoked on every line read by awk. I can only guess what you are trying to do but awk can surely handle two (or more) files simultaneously. Can you give more details? Sample input files and desired output?

Comment: I already have a nawk block which reads a file with 20000 records in which one of the field is country and I want a small block for ISO code lookup - I thought of having it in a separate array and then use it in the nawk block whenever i get the country - Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

system returns the exit value of the called command, but the output of the command is not returned to awk (or nawk).  To get the output, you want to use getline directly.  For example, you might re-write your script:

```
awk ' {
file = "/tmp/OFAC/country_codes.config";
CITIZEN_COUNTRY_NAME = "INDIA";
FS = "@";
while( getline < file ) {
    if( $0 ~ CITIZEN_COUNTRY_NAME ) {
        CITIZENSHIP_CODE = $1;
    }
}
close( file );
}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help . This is exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly - Really Really appreciate it - I have one more question on this. I have one more question the country look up file would have approximately 260 records and there will be around 20,000 input records so per this code for 20 K records theere would be 260 lines read - Will this be OK or can we have this rewritten using grep command - Pls advise - Thanks

Comment: getline will probably be just as slow as using grep.  Searching through the lookup file for each record is probably a bad idea.  But awk is good for this sort of thing; read the country lookup once and build an array, then read the input records and output data from the array.

Comment: I face an issue whenever there is a bracket in the country name ()
or a single apostrope '

Sample values

CIV@COTE D'IVOIRE
COD@CONGO, Democratic Republic of (was Zaire)

Can you pls help me overcome these 2 issues.

Comment: What's the issue?  If you can simplify the code to detect the source of the problem, you will probably find the solution.  (Parentheses and single quotes should not be a problem, and in the simple cases I've tried I have not been able to detect any problems.)

Answer (score 0):

Pre-load the config file with awk:

```
nawk '
  NR == FNR {
    split($0, x, "@")
    country_code[x[2]] = x[1]
    next
  }
  {
    CITIZEN_COUNTRY_NAME = "INDIA"
    if (CITIZEN_COUNTRY_NAME in country_code) {
      value = country_code[CITIZEN_COUNTRY_NAME]
    } else {
      value = "null"
    }
    print "found " value " for country name " CITIZEN_COUNTRY_NAME
  }
' country_codes.config  filename
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help . This is exactly what I was looking for and it works perfectly - Really Really appreciate it - I have one more question on this. I have one more question the country look up file would have approximately 260 records and there will be around 20,000 input records so per this code for 20 K records theere would be 260 lines read - Will this be OK or can we have this rewritten using grep command - Pls advise

Comment: With this awk code, you read the 260 records once, and for each of the 20K input records you're just doing an array lookup which is very fast. Otherwise, you performing a grep for every input record (20,000 grep processes), clearly much less efficient.

Comment: I tried escuting this nawk block by invoking form the main and using some echo - None of the system echo used inside was printed can you pls help me here - See details of the code edited in my original question

Comment: @user549432, I don't understand your comment. Please post some code. Also, "system echo"? Why not just print?

Comment: @ Glen - Please find the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338710/unix-awk-array-not-printing-values - Thanks for all your help